# How to construct two particle Brownian trajectory with respect to time in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, simulation

I am studying a MATLAB code for constructing two dimensional Brownian motion trajectory generation,  [from this link](http://lben.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/lben/files/users/179705/Simulating%20Brownian%20Motion.pdf), it is given as:

```
particle = struct();
particle.x = cumsum( randn(N, 1) );
particle.y = cumsum( randn(N, 1) );
plot(particle.x, particle.y);
ylabel('Y Position');
xlabel('X Position');
title('position versus time in 2D');
```

I want to generate two such Brownian particles but with a time gap i.e. suppose one particle is generated at '0' time than another one is at time 't'. I have no clue as how to incorporate this, in the this or some other code. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above script is calculating the position of the particle after `N` steps. The only difference between your two particles is that they have traveled a different number of steps. Consequently, you just have to plug different values of `N` in:

```
% First Particle
N1 = 100;
particle1 = struct();
particle1.x = cumsum( randn(N1, 1) );
particle1.y = cumsum( randn(N1, 1) );

% Second Particle
N2 = 200;
particle2 = struct();
particle2.x = cumsum( randn(N2, 1) );
particle2.y = cumsum( randn(N2, 1) );

% Plot
figure;
hold on
plot(particle1.x, particle1.y, 'r');
plot(particle2.x, particle2.y, 'b');
ylabel('Y Position');
xlabel('X Position');
title('position versus time in 2D');
```

This gives me the following:
[image: Brownian Motion]

Comment: That is, of course, assuming point-like non-interacting particles (which is what, I believe, the question was about).

Comment: Also; I'd add `axis equal;` since the x and y displacement are on the same scale.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!

Answer (score 2):

Just to highlight @RPM 's answer; here is some code which shows the animation of 10 successive launches of independent particles from (0,0):

```
close all; clear; clc;

N = 1e3; % Number of steps overall
Np = 10; % Number of diffusing particles
delay = 100; % Delay (in steps) between the launches

% Initialise particles at (0,0)
for k = 1:Np
   particle(k).x = nan(N,1); particle(k).x(1) = 0; %#ok<SAGROW>
   particle(k).y = nan(N,1); particle(k).y(1) = 0; %#ok<SAGROW>
end

% Take N-1 random steps
figure(1); axes;
for j = 2:N
    for k = 1:ceil((j-1)./delay)
        particle(k).x(j) = particle(k).x(j-1) + randn;
        particle(k).y(j) = particle(k).y(j-1) + randn;
    end
    for k = (ceil((j-1)./delay)+1):Np
        particle(k).x(j) = particle(k).x(j-1);
        particle(k).y(j) = particle(k).y(j-1);
    end
    % Plot the step
    plot(particle(1).x, particle(1).y); hold on;
    for k = 2:Np
        plot(particle(k).x, particle(k).y);
    end
    hold off;
    axis equal;
    title(sprintf('#%d',j));
    drawnow; pause(0.01);
end
```

This is **just for demonstration**. Please use @RPM 's code - `rand(N,1)` as opposed to a for loop!